# Known posets of tilting modules for finite dimensional algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

> Question: For which classes of finite dimensional algebras $A$ is the poset of tilting $A$-modules known?

Here two famous examples:

-For the path algebra of a linear oriented quiver of Dynkin type $A_n$ we obtain the Tamari, lattice see for example page 226 of [https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~hkrause/HomTheRep.pdf](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Ehkrause/HomTheRep.pdf).

-For the Auslander algebra of $K[x]/(x^n)$, one obtains the symmetric group with the left weak order, see for example theorem 1.1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.05037.pdf.

What can be said about the poset of tilting modules for path algebras of Euclidean type or the $n$-Kronecker path algebra? Is something known about the poset of tilting modules of the incidence algebra of a Boolean lattice?

Comment: Small comment: I have never heard "left order" as a shorthand for "left weak order." I am somewhat sympathetic to the idea that "weak order" is not a great name (it suggests a weakening of the property of being a partial order, and "Bruhat order" is a better name than "strong order" too). But I would suggest "(left) permutohedral order" if you are looking for an alternative name.

Comment: ("Left" versus "right" is its own can of worms. We multiply on the left by simple transpositions to go up in left weak order, but this corresponds to *right* divisibility in the classical positive braid monoid...)

Comment: @SamHopkins I actually just forgot the name "weak" but I agree that the name is not very good.

Comment: Well the paper you link to also just uses "left order" and not "left weak order."

Answer (score 6):

This is not really an answer but I don't have enough reputation to comment.

In the hereditary case, tilting modules and $\tau$-tilting modules coincide. Moreover the poset of tilting modules can be deduced from the poset of torsion classes (or the poset of support $\tau$-tilting modules). Indeed the map sending a tilting module $T$ to the torsion class $Fac(T)$ is injective. Moreover a torsion class is of this form if and only if it contains the injective modules. So the poset of tilting modules is the upper ideal generated by $Fac(D(A))$ in the poset of torsion classes. You can find this in the Chapter 6 of the Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras.

In Dynkin type the posets of torsion classes are the cambrian lattices of Reading, so we have a good knowledge of the poset of tilting modules.

For the Kronecker with two arrows the poset of torsion classes can be found in many articles on tau-tilting theory and the poset of tilting modules can be easily deduced: it is a total order whose Hasse diagram has two connected components. One for the pre-projective part of the AR-quiver and one for the pre-injective part. The modules in the pre-projective parts are all smaller than the one for the pre-injective part.

I computed once the poset for a path algebra of type $\widetilde{A}_2$, the Hasse diagram also has two connected components but this time the poset is not a lattice.

For non hereditary case the situation is more complicated since there are two notions of tilting modules: the classical tilting modules and the generalized tilting modules. For the generalized tilting modules Jan Geuenich computed them for the Auslander algebra of $k[X]/(X^n)$. The answer is very nice: the poset is isomorphic to the so-called rational permutation braids ordered using the weak ordering. The poset of generalized tilting modules must be known in many other examples but I don't know where to look for. The poset of classical tilting modules can in theory be deduced from (a good knowledge of) the support tau-tilting modules since the tilting modules are the faithful support tau-tilting modules.